# combine Strings and vars in Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Hi i need to make these Options changeabel:

#### values.yaml

```
connector:
  proxyname: "xx.${{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx"

ingress:
  hosts:
    - host: xx.${{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx
  tls:
      hosts: 
        - xx.${{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx
```

my understanding was i can call it now like this:

```
helm install newpod -f ... --set context=${{ github.event.inputs.context }} .
```

But after i call this i get the following message:

```
.... [spec.rules[0].host: Invalid value: "xx.{{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx" ....
```

how can i deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved [using tpl function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks#using-the-tpl-function)

**values.yaml**

```yaml
context: test

connector:
  proxyname: "xx.{{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx"
```

**manifest.yaml**

```yaml
test: {{ tpl .Values.connector.proxyname . }}
```

If you need to use them in your ingress inside a range, use `$` to point to the root context

**ingress.yaml**

```yaml
...
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ tpl . $ | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ tpl .host $ | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
...
```

**NOTES.txt**

```
...
http{{ if $.Values.ingress.tls }}s{{ end }}://{{ tpl $host.host $ }}{{ . }}
...
```

Comment: what does test here refer to?
can you apply your example to mine? concretely to the connector for example.
Sry but i dont get it.

Comment: @klatuu since you posted just the values file and not the resource where these values are being used, `test` is just an arbitrary value from an arbitrary resource. You should use the expression between `{{ }}` where you use `.Values.connector.proxyname` and other values.

Comment: oh ah okay, thanks. so Connector i found and was easy to replace,
but the other 2 are ingress like and i found it here:
    `{{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }} - host: {{ .host | quote }} `
and here
    `- hosts: {{- range .hosts }} - {{ . | quote }} {{- end }}`
so i place the tpl in the `{{- range tpl .host }}` ?

Comment: @klatuu added ingress example to my answer

Comment: `1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  https://xx.{{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx/`
he dont evaluate it
May Fault, its only the output from the NOTES file everything is fine

Comment: can you help me 1 more time plz? how must i change the NOTES.txt to get the right output. `https://{{ .Values.dnsname }}.{{ .Values.context }}.xx.xx/`. In the Notes file it looks like this: `{{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
  {{- range .paths }}
  http{{ if $.Values.ingress.tls }}s{{ end }}://{{ $host.host }}{{ . }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}`

Comment: added notes.txt